# Second instance of Instagram on Android 11

Tags: instagram

Does anyone know if I can install 2 different instances of Instagram on Android 11 (like you can do with some other apps?
I know that I can have up to 5 account on Instagram, but I would like to separate my work and personal accounts separate to manage it more effectively.

Comment: There are apps like "Parallel Space" that allows to run some apps in a second instance. See also https://beebom.com/best-parallel-space-alternatives/

Comment: [How to use two different numbers in the same phone via WhatsApp?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204367/218526)